# Finding the AverageIf of the highest three numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the average of column G based on the three largest numbers in column B.

The formula I've tried is:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B7:B131,LARGE(B7:B131,{1,2,3}),G7:G131)
```

The problem is it does not average the three, but rather it only displays the column G equivalent to the largest number in column B.

Does anybody know the correct formula to use in this instance?

Comment: Are the numbers unique? This gets much more complicated if the numbers appear more than once in column B...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the numbers are all different in `column B`, as you say, then you can do this most easily by averaging `column G` for any number in `column B` that's greater than or equal to the 3rd largest, i.e.

`=AVERAGEIF(B7:B131,">="&LARGE(B7:B131,3),G7:G131)`

Comment: This is a much more simple solution. I had tried this method, but left out the & causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get matching values (from the same row) from different columns, you can use either `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX\MATCH`, as I did here.

From that point it gets trivial. Let me know if it works for you:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(LARGE(B:B,1),B:B,0),1), 
         INDEX(G:G,MATCH(LARGE(B:B,2),B:B,0),1),  
         INDEX(G:G,MATCH(LARGE(B:B,3),B:B,0),1))
```

(*Please notice I assumed the values in column B are unique, as you've mentioned in your comment.*)